# Network Bridge keeps disconnecting WiFi after Reboot

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wireless-bridge

I have set up a network bridge on my Win10 machine to connect the attached Corp-WiFi to a local RJ45 that has an access point attached to it so that mobile devices in the area can have internet access through a Guest-WiFi. The Access-Point also connects a second wired device on its own LAN.

The original SSID of the Corp-WiFi is hidden and cannot be avaiable for the mobile devices.

The bridge itself works fine as long as I connect the WiFi. As soon as I restart the PC, the WiFi connection is not automatically restored and so neither is the bridge. I have to restore the WiFi connection manually for it to work again.

The auto-connect checkbox is checked, and when I delete the network bridge, an automatic connection is made every time I reboot (15/15 success).

This is supposed to be an automatic system and the network bridge needs to exist.

So the specific problem is that the WiFi adapter has to reconnect automatically after a system reboot, which it currently does not do, although the corresponding checkboxes are enabled for it.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Have you asked the Company for settings that work ?  Also make sure Ethernet remains disconnected

Comment: @John I have asked them and also the setup works perfectly fine as it should once I open the network panel and hit "connect" on the WiFi. 

Just doesn't reconnect automatically after reboot, although the checkbox is set.